# На приеме у врача

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> На приеме у врача:
>   - Доктор, у меня болит всё!
>   - Ну это вы загнули, батенька: на всё у вас денег не хватит.

***На приеме у врача*** - это неполное предложение или другая синтаксическая конструкция? Включаются ли такие конструкции в разряд неполных предложений? Являются ли такие конструкции предложениями вообще?

Answer (score 1):

Это **номинативное предложение** (собственно бытийное)  с интродуктивной функцией, оно вводит, представляет место, время, обстоятельства для дальнейшего повествования. Такие предложения характерны для начала рассказа, очерка.

Например: **Земская больница.** За отсутствием доктора, уехавшего жениться, больных принимает фельдшер Курятин... (Чехов).

Comment: Спасибо! Но здесь не именительный падеж. Как быть?